# Bootstrap tabs pills disabling and with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I looked at the below example and am trying to add additional functionality. I would like to disable other two tables initially and when I submit the form from first tab and then enable second tab. I have tried using jQuery UO and jQuery. But not able to do with Bootstrap and jQuery.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/110/)

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#profile').attr('class', 'disabled');
    $('#message').attr('class', 'disabled');
    $('#profile').removeAttr('data-toggle');
    $('#messages').removeAttr('data-toggle');
});
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To disable the other two tabs and later on enable them on an event you can do the following,

http://jsfiddle.net/5zjXk/1/

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*disable non active tabs*/
    $('.nav li').not('.active').addClass('disabled');
/*to actually disable clicking the bootstrap tab, as noticed in comments by user3067524*/
    $('.nav li').not('.active').find('a').removeAttr("data-toggle");

    $('button').click(function(){
        /*enable next tab*/
        $('.nav li.active').next('li').removeClass('disabled');
        $('.nav li.active').next('li').find('a').attr("data-toggle","tab")
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

    <div id='content' class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
        </ul>
          <button>submit</button>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
        <ul>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
            <li>profile</li>
        </ul>
          <button>submit</button>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
          Tetsing
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. Thoug it appears as disabled, i am able to click on it.

Comment: @user3067524 indeed, i didn't notice. Please find an update here http://jsfiddle.net/5zjXk/1/  . I will also update the answer.

Comment: Here is my fina lversion. Evryting looks great except, on intial load it is not showing any content on the firs ttab and not able to click. http://jsfiddle.net/5zjXk/2/

Comment: Nevermind. I found the problem, am not using "tab-pane active" in right location.Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/5zjXk/3/

Comment: if users chnages any input form fields in previous tab, i need to disable all following tabs. Can you help please? Tx!

Comment: @user3067524 you can listen for a `change` event using `jQuery`, then disable the next tab, for example, `$('input,select').on('change',function(){$('.nav li.active').next('li').addClass('disabled');
    $('.nav li.active').next('li').find('a').removeAttr("data-toggle");});` .  http://jsfiddle.net/xg2jr/ . This will need a little work to cover cases of having 10 tabs and changing the 3rd, but you get the idea and it basically depends on the behaviour you desire for your system.

Comment: Hi there, i am trying to post a new question but having trouble posting due to formating. I jsut saw your comment and wouldl ike to ask you!. Thank you for the above suggetion. I iwll give a try.Pl take a look at my complete protoype. http://jsfiddle.net/aQGEF

Comment: 1. How can i move calendar icon next by the date field?  
2. Why the calendar is popped when page is loading? It is working fine in my local server but not sure what is the issue in JSFiddle.  
3. Is there any way I can set the size of the date field as 10 so there will be no extra space in the input field?

Comment: @user3067524 Please accept the answer since it resolved your initial issue, so that other visitors can be assisted. Thanks.  Regarding your new issue please try to post a separate question as it is a new issue. Thanks.  p.s. have a look here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal  it may help you on the last issue you mentioned.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thank you very much for all your great help. I really appreaicte it. Yes I will continue try posting my new question. I am just having tough time formating it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).delegate('li.disabled a').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false; });
```

even if you dynamically add the 'disabled' class it will still work. cheers.