# How to disable a nav-pill hover effect just in one item in the navbar with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to disable the nav-pill hover effect on just one item, the link that changes the language of the page, in my navbar. What is the best way to achieve this using either a bootstrap class or CSS?

```
<div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">
                                <li class="language language-active disabled">NL</li>
                                <li class="language language-nonactive language-right"><a href="/en/index.html">EN</a></li>
                                <li class="approach-li"><a href="diensten.html">Diensten</a></li>
                                <li class="about-li"><a href="overons.html">Over ons</a></li>
                            <li class="qa-li"><a href="vragen.html">Vragen</a></li> 
                                <li class="about-li"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>            
                                <li class="navbarpadding">
                                      <form action="afspraak.html">
                                                <button class="btn navbar-btn btn-primary2">Afspraak maken</button>
                                        </form>
                                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your html using the class: ".language-nonactive"

You can these styles to go along with it, this will remove the hover of the grey background:

```
.nav>li.language-nonactive>a:hover, .nav>li.language-nonactive>a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle to show what I've done:

http://jsfiddle.net/ho1sgm1e/

Additionally you could you something like this with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*disable non active tabs*/
  $('.nav li').not('.active').addClass('disabled');
  /*to actually disable clicking the bootstrap tab, as noticed in comments by user3067524*/
  $('.nav li').not('.active').find('a').removeAttr("data-toggle");  
});
```

source: [Bootstrap tabs pills disabling and with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668880/bootstrap-tabs-pills-disabling-and-with-jquery)

Furthermore, utilising the disbaled class will effectively disable the button.

Comment: You should mention that you've copied the code from [Bootstrap tabs pills disabling and with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20670195/3793448). Please give credit to the original post

Comment: Added that to the java script part of my answer, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS:

```
.nav .language-nonactive a:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

## Demo